# Other ways than for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, shapes, tensor

I'm creating a new tensor with the right dimensions, but it's taken forever using a for loop. Is there a faster way to do this? Maybe just changing the shape of the orignial tensor.

In general im creating a neural network, and the reason for why I have to change the shape is for it to fit with my other input in the network.

This is a sample from the data:

```
    labels_numeric_copy = [8, 3, 7, 4, 4, 5, 4, 8, 5, 4, 4, 8, 4, 6]
```

This is the code for this part of the code.

```
frames = np.empty((32000, 100))
for i in range (len(labels_numeric_copy)):
    np.append(frames,labels_numeric_copy[i])
```

I already tried reshape and view. Any ideas?

Comment: Your code is not reproducible. What is `labels_numeric_copy`? Please add the relevant code to your question which allows others to answer your question. Please read how to add a [mre]

Comment: It's a list with 32000 statements converted to numeric values. I was not sure how I should add this here

Comment: Add a smaller sample from that list. When asking a question on SO, you have to use a smaller representative example of your problem as input and the corresponding output for that. Simplify the question by building your code on a smaller set of inputs and then once it behaves as intended, scale it up.

Comment: instead of iterating an index over the length of an iterable, you can directly iterate the elements. so instead of `for i in range(len(my_array)):  print(my_array[i])`  you can do `for elem in my_array: print(elem)`